# How does a ghost hunter use the screwdriver and string in the “gost [sic] hunting kit?”

Tags: equipment, call-of-cthulhu, pregenerated-characters

Using a pre-generated character — Maximilian Hirst, parapsychologist — I have a ghost hunting kit consisting of a thermometer, string, screwdriver, and bible. Neither the GM (nor I) could come up with a reason or method of use for the string and screwdriver. Is it a plumb line thing? Some kind of ley line detection?

This pre-generated character is included in [*Doors to Darkness: Five Scenarios for Beginning Keepers*](https://www.chaosium.com/doors-to-darkness-hardcover/) (p. 135). The "gost [sic] hunting kit"  is listed under his **Equipment** as including "talcum powder, thermometer, string, screw driver, *Holy Bible*".

Comment: The mention of thermometer and string make me thing it might be a **go**vernment **st**andard hunting kit, i.e. the toolset of a [metrologist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrologist).

Comment: @vicky_molokh If the string is wet, it's raining. If it's dry, it's sunny. if it's waving around, it's windy. if it's burnt to ashes, watch out for lightning.

Comment: @AdmiralJota That's met**eo**rology, which different too.

Comment: Are you asking for answers based on official material and/or gameplay experience? If you don't limit it in such a way, it seems sort of like idea-generation, where answers are just unsupported speculation; that wouldn't really be a good fit for the RPG.SE format.

Answer (score 1):

Strings can be stretched across openings and secured with tape: any physical object that passes through the opening would pull the string loose.

A bit of string can be wedged into a doorframe: if the door is open, the string falls to the ground.

Screwdrivers are useful for tightening things, loosening things, prying things, and probing things.
You could also use it to affix a screw on either side of an opening as anchor points for your string.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you support your answer by citing evidence or gameplay experience?